# Using the Cholesky decomposition of a matrix instead of its square root to compute eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

It seems that the following two matrices have the same eigenvalues: $A^{-1/2} B A^{-1/2}$ and $L^{-1} B L^{-\top}$ where $L L^\top$ is the Cholesky decomposition of $A$.  Both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive-definite matrices.

**How can I prove this?** I'm not even sure where to start from.

PS: There seems to be a common confusion between Cholesky factors $L$ and matrix square roots, see, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2767873/261538) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3004411/261538), and probably this property is one of the reasons.  Yet I couldn't find this specific question asked elsewhere.

PPS: This is not a homework, I'm trying to understand why this yields the same eigenvalues since it seems to be a more computationally efficient way of finding geodesic distances between SPD matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues. That's why. So, if $\sigma(X)$ denotes the set of eigenvalues of $X$, then
$$
\sigma(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}) = \sigma(BA^{-1}) = \sigma(BL^{-T}L^{-1}) = \sigma(L^{-1}BL^{-T}).
$$